# single checkbox with yes or no values

Tags: html

Is it possible to have a single checkbox with two values ? i have a checkbox called "full-day ?".

```html
 <div class="input-field col s2">
              <p>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test6" value="yes" ng-model="isFull"/>
          <label for="test6">Half Day</label>
       </p>
            </div>
```

if the user checks it a yes should be passed when i press submit button and if the checkbox is not checked a no have to be passed.As far as i know if the checkbox is not activated html treats as if checkbox is not present and it wont be included in the query string.Here using radio button is not an option.Please let me know how do i go about it.

Comment: i mean when you submit form data the checkbox wont be included if it is not active right ? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Bhavik — No. It doesn't. Only checked checkboxes are successful.

Answer (score 4):

This is simple:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="test6" value="no" ng-model="isFull" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="test6" value="yes" ng-model="isFull">

<label for="test6">Half Day</label>
```

1. It is boolean.
2. Code is processed sequentially
3. Only the last 'checked' answer is used.

Therefore put the 'non' answer first but hide it and leave it always checked. The positive answer comes second.

If the form is editable (user can come back and change their answer) code to check the single visible checkbox appropriately e.g.

```
<?php if ($fieldValue=='Yes' ){ echo 'checked'; } ?>
```

Works for me!

Comment: this is a bit hackish, but works flawlessly.. it's a pity that the OP never flagged this as best reply

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You can fake things with JavaScript that injects hidden inputs, but this is better handled with server side code.

e.g.

```
my $value;
if ($request->param("checkbox_name") {
    $value = "yes";
} else {
    $value = "no";
}
```

Comment: how to do this before form submission ??